# Taking Filetype and Filesize While uploading from php and add to the database

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I want to upload an file from form and when I click submit it uploads the file to the server and insert filename, filesize and filetype from that file. but I always get errors like:

Warning: "filesize(): "stat failed for "uploadedfile" in C:\wamp\www\Project2\members\uploaded.php on line 14"

Warning: filetype(): "Lstat failed for "uploadedfile" in C:\wamp\www\Project2\members\uploaded.php on line 15"

Here is my uploadfile.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$username =$_SESSION["uname"];
?>
<title>Uploading Page</title>
<b>Hello again,<?php echo $username ?>. From here, you can select your image or file and upload our database.</b>
<form action="uploaded.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my uploaded.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<title>Uploading Page</title>
<?php
session_start();
$username =$_SESSION["uname"];
?>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webpage");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $filename = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $filesize = filesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $filetype = filetype($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "<br>File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".</br>";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "<br>File is not an image.</br>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<br>Sorry, file already exists.</br>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000000000) {
    echo "<br>Sorry, your file is too large.</br>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "<br>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</br>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<br>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</br>";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
       $sql=mysqli_query($con,"insert into datas(username,imagesnotes,size,type) values('$username','$filename','$filesize')");
    if(!$sql)
    {
    echo "<br>there is a problem in MySQL please check again.</br>";
    }
       echo "<br>The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.</br>";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</br>";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```